# C++ What would be the best way to set a maximum number for an integer in the function parameters

Tags: c++, integer

I have a problem. I will use a hypothetical example as I do not think that I need to use my actual function as it is kind of complex. This is the example:

```
int GetNumberTimesTwo(int num)
{
    return num * 2;
}
```

Now, let's assume that if the Number is bigger than two something bad happens. Is there any way how I can force `num` to be less or equal than 2? Of course, I could do

```
int GetNumberTimesTwo(int num)
{
    if (num > 2)
        return;
    return num * 2;
}
```

The problem is that this would be annoying as it just prevents this from happening, but I would like to know about this error before compiling. Meaning, is there something like `int num < 2` that I can do?
In my dreams, it could be done like that:

```
int GetNumberTimesTwo(int num < 2)
{
    return num * 2;
}
```

But as I said, in my dreams, and because I know C++, I know that nothing ever works like I would like it to work, therefore I have to ask what the correct way to do this is.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the value of a variable at compile time. That can only happen at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> C++ What would be the best way to set a maximum number for an integer in the function parameters

There are basically two alternatives:

1. Decide how to handle invalid input at runtime.
2. Accept a parameter type whose all possible values are valid, thereby making it impossible to pass invalid input.

For 1. there are many alternatives. Here are some:

- Simply document the requirement as a precondition and violating the precondition results in undefined behaviour. Assume that input is always valid and don't check for invalid values. This is the most efficient choice, but least safe.
- Throw an exception.
- Return `std::expected` (proposed, not yet standard feature) or similar class which contains either result, or error state.

For 2. There are no trivial fool-proof choices. For a small set of valid values, an enum class is reasonably difficult to misuse:

```
enum class StrangeInput {
    zero = 0,
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
};

int GetNumberTimesTwo(StrangeInput num)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the compiler knows how to validate this, and if it does what would be the error? stop compiling?

The problem is that you are passing a variable to the function, In the universe of possible values of ints there are for sure values greater than 2 so how would the compiler know that in your execution you are never passing that amount.

This is a typical runtime validation, you should be validating the preconditions in your function and handle these scenarios in case unexpected values comes.

Answer (score 0):

With template and/or `constexpr`, you might have some kind of check, but requires value known at compile time and possibly restrict available functions to call inside the function:

```
template <int N>
int GetNumberTimesTwo()
{
    static_assert(N <= 2);
    return N * 2;
}
```

```
constexpr int GetNumberTimesTwo(int num)
{
    // only code valid for constexpr
    // the restrictions has changed with standard
    if (num > 2) throw std::runtime_error("out of range");
    return num * 2;
}

constexpr int ok = GetNumberTimesTwo(1);
constexpr int ko = GetNumberTimesTwo(42); // Compile time error
int no_check1 = GetNumberTimesTwo(1);  // ok at runtime
int no_check2 = GetNumberTimesTwo(42); // throw at runtime
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the way to go:

```
int GetNumberTimesTwo(int num)
{
    if (num > 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return num * 2;
}
```

or throw an error:

```
int GetNumberTimesTwo(int num)
{
    if (num < 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("count cannot be negative!");
    }
    return num * 2;
}
```

Comment: already saw the error... but thanks for the comment @eerorika

Comment: OK, now what happens when the caller passes 0? That satisfies the precondition of being less than or equal to 0, but results in a value that represents invalid input.